# Search date with specific label through textview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

i got some stuck because i want to use the textview to search the date and show the data i want. but only the hard code i can do, and i dunno how to make the search through the textview and display the data i search the date.

how do i search the date, because i set the date as label, but i need my recyclerview to know what my date is showed.

[image]

here's the sample

[image]

```
    date = findViewById(R.id.DateTextView);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.staffList);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    attendances = new ArrayList<Attendance>();
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int YEAR = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int MONTH = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int DATE = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ViewAttendActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                    calendar1.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
                    String dateText = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy", calendar1).toString();
                    date.setText(dateText);
                }
            }, YEAR, MONTH, DATE);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    String dateString = date.toString();

if (dateString.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(ViewAttendActivity.this, "Please Select Date First!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance").child("08-15-2021");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance").child(dateString);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Attendance attendance = dataSnapshot.getValue(Attendance.class);
                    attendances.add(attendance);
                }
                editStaffAttendAdapter = new EditStaffAttendAdapter(attendances, ViewAttendActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(editStaffAttendAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewAttendActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: well that's my expect code, when the list is hidden by default, there's a textview need to choose a date, after chose the date, then the list is showed, but now i only know inside the code, only the hard code i did, but how to let user choose date and display the result of staff list. that's my errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the string showed by a textview using the `.getText().toString()` attribute, like this:

```
TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DateTextView);

//Retrieve the text showed by the date TextView
String dateShowedByTextView = date.getText().toString();
```

Comment: that i tried, it works. but i need some like "list is hidden before user choose, list is showed when user choose the date" function.